# PHP preg_match_all, read content and exclude unwanted

Tags: php

I have a text file I want to read, but exclude lines that contain certain character at the start (hence "@", or whatever one defined later):

```
@ I don't want this line to be read
This line should be read;
"This one" should be read, too;
'Also this one' should be read;
...etc
@ But this one should be ignored;
```

With below code I can explode those that ends with a semicolon (";"), but the last line should not, because it begins with a "@".

```
$contents = file_get_contents($the_path);
$result = array_map('trim', explode(";", $contents));
```

Any hint to achieve this? Thanks

**UPDATE the codes:**

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257244/php-preg-match-all-read-content-and-exclude-unwanted/10257319
  $results = array();
  $matches = array();
  $the_path = '/path/to/file.txt';
  if (is_file($the_path)) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($the_path);
    if ($contents) {
      // ! array warning
      // $contents = array_map('rtrim', $contents);
      // $matches = preg_grep('#^@#', $contents, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
      $matches = preg_split("/[\r\n]/", preg_replace("/@.*?[\r\n]/", "", $contents), NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

      if ($matches) {
        foreach ($matches as $key => $val) {
          $results[$key] = $val;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // Attempt to remove the first 0 key, and start from 1, because 0|value0 is considered NULL
  $results = array_combine(range(1, count($results)), array_values($results));

  return !empty($results) ? $results : array();
```

**UPDATE 2, works properly via DCoder:**

```
  $matches = array();
  if ($contents = file($the_path)) {
      $contents = array_map('rtrim', $contents);
      $keyword = '@';
      // Still output @line
      // $matches = preg_grep('#^@#', $contents, PREG_GREP_INVERT); 
      // Ok, thanks to http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-grep.php#85503
      $matches = preg_grep("/{$keyword}/i", $contents, PREG_GREP_INVERT);         

      // $matches = preg_split("/[\r\n]/", preg_replace("/@.*?[\r\n]/", "", $contents), NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
      // dsm($matches);
      if ($matches) {
        foreach ($matches as $key => $match) {
         $results[$key] = $match;
        }
      }
  }


  // $results = array_combine(range(1, count($results)), array_values($results));
  return $results;
```

Comment: just use array_shift($results); to remove the first entry

Comment: Thanks. It was tried previously before ended up with that ugly line

Comment: Thanks, I always accept answers, except for those without answers :(.

Comment: so my answer is neither an answer nor did help you?

Comment: Almost work, except for empty 0|'' pairs. And using array_shift() nullifies them all.

Comment: as i said, give us your complete input data.... ie. on http://pastebin.com

Comment: Just remembered. The reason I didn't use array_shift(), because I wanted to get rid of 0|value pairs, and started from 1|value1, because my CMS read 0 as NULL, even though there is value in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// get the contents of the file as an array of lines
$contents = file($the_path);
if($contents === false) {
    throw new Exception("Failed to open file {$the_path}");
}
// drop ending newlines
$contents = array_map('rtrim', $contents);

// find all lines except those starting with @
$matched = preg_grep('#^@#', $contents, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
```

Comment: Thanks, but still get array warning, maybe in my code somewhere. Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array

Comment: Make sure the file you're trying to open does exist (`file` returns FALSE if it can't read it).

Comment: Yes, with is_file($the_path) as usual

Comment: @swan: Now that you've added the new code, the error makes more sense: you are doing `$contents = file_get_contents($the_path);`, but my code example is doing `$contents = file($the_path);`. Your version returns the whole file in a single string, my version returns an array (each line as a separate element).

Comment: Strange, previous it (the removal of line with @) worked, except for array which has been fixed, but now @line appears after all cache clear

Answer (score 1):

with this code the $lines will contain an array with all lines which do not start with an `@`

```
$contents = file_get_contents($the_path);
$lines = preg_split("/[\r\n]/", preg_replace("/@.*?[\r\n]/", "", $contents), null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: Almost works, except that it adds an empty 0|'' pairs which are not expected

Comment: can you provide the full data for which it does not work properly?

Comment: Do you know how to remove the last 0|'' pairs. array_shift nullified the results.

Comment: btw, array_unshift does NOT nullify all resulst. you maybe use it wrong. just do `array_unshift($results);`, not `$results = array_unshift($results);`

Comment: Thanks. Added http://pastebin.com/yUjfcqWg, how do you excecute PHP there? Not allowed?

Comment: Thanks a lot, DCoder approach solved the 0|val0. Your code also works except for that 0. Thanks a lot for help